# How to Move Zero Qty Products to the end of List when i have a PagedList<Products>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, razor

I have a method in my controller which returns a `PagedList` to my category-page View that contains **Products** (based current ***Page-Number*** and ***Page-Size*** which user has selected) from SQL Server stored-procedure like blow :

```
var products = _dbContext.EntityFromSql<Product>("ProductLoad",
pCategoryIds,
pManufacturerId,
pOrderBy,
pageIndex,
pageSize).ToList(); // returning products based selected Ordering by.
var totalRecords = pTotalRecords.Value != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(pTotalRecords.Value) : 0;
var allPrd= new PagedList<Product>(products, pageIndex, pageSize, totalRecords);
```

**An Example of sending parameters to db stored-procedure is :**

```
("ProductLoad",
[1,10,13],
[653],
"Lowest Price",
 2,
 64) // so it returns second 64 products with those category-ids and Brand-ids sorting by lowest to highest price
```

It's working fine , but what i am trying to do is **always sending products with 0 quantity to the end of list**.

**For example** :
if i had 10k products which 2k of them have 0 quantity , i need to show this 8k products first and then 2k unavailable products in the end of list)

what i have **tried so far** is always loading All products without page-size and page-index first then send zero qty products to the end of the list by this and finally `Pagedlist` with fixing page size :

```
 ("ProductLoad",
 [1,10,13],
 [653],
 "Lowest Price",
  0,
  10000) // fixed page size means loading all products   

 var zeroQty= from p in products
                    where p.StockQuantity==0
                    select p;

  var zeroQtyList= zeroQty.ToList();
  products = products.Except(zeroQtyList).ToList();
  products.AddRange(zeroQtyList);

  var totalRecords = pTotalRecords.Value != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(pTotalRecords.Value) : 0;
  var allPrd= new PagedList<Product>(products, pageIndex, 64, totalRecords);
```

It cause all zero qty Products goes to the end of list.

But **it always loads all products** that is **not a good idea and for sure not an optimized way , sometime users get page loading time-out**,
(because category-page show 64 products in every page-index-number) every time user opens a page in the website, all products would loads and it cause **delay** in loading page.

> Is there anyway to solve this problem (have a `PagedList` which
>   contains all more than zero qty products first and 0 qty products
>   second)  **without changing stored-procedure**? (fixing loading page
>   delays)

**P.S :** The reason i avoid changing stored-procedure is it has already too much join,temp-table Union and Order by.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you are going to have to bite the bullet and change the stored procedure to handle the paging. There is also the possibility of doing it in LINQ To Entities but if your SP is as complicated as you make it sound, then that's probably more trouble than it's worth. Any other way will involve getting all 10K records and then doing the sorting/paging in C# code which as you have already seen, is going to be slow.

Comment: I would say 2 ways: 1 change the stored procedure and add a 'virtual' bool column that is true for 'more than 0' and false for '0', then hard sort (ie don't allow user to sort) on that. this will always force '0' poducts to the end. The other would be to put your 'take' into a 'while' and inspect the results when they come back from the db. while they have '0 qty' records, and there are more records left, keep querying

Comment: @Jonathan i am already a trying to change sp unfortunately, but i hope there is any renovate way to store All products for PagedList without delay. thank you for your suggest :)

Comment: @howcheng nobody answered  , may you please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to the use the [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function in your stored procedure.

This is an example of how I have done this before. Hopefully you will be able to adapt it to your SP.

```
--temp table to hold the message IDs we are looking for
CREATE TABLE #ids (
     MessageId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ,RowNum INT PRIMARY KEY
);

--insert all message IDs that match the search criteria, with row number
INSERT INTO #ids
SELECT m.[MessageId]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreatedUTC DESC)
  FROM [dbo].[Message] m WITH (NOLOCK)
 WHERE ....

DECLARE @total INT;
SELECT @total = COUNT(1) FROM #ids;

--determine which records we want to select
--note: @skip and @take are parameters of the procedure
IF @take IS NULL
    SET @take = @total;
DECLARE @startRow INT, @endRow INT;
SET @startRow = @skip + 1;
SET @endRow = @skip + @take;

-- select the messages within the requested range
SELECT m.* FROM [dbo].[Message] WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN #ids i ON m.MessageId = i.MessageId
WHERE i.RowNum BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow;
```

Comment: thank you if i don't find any other way to edit code will go for stored-procedure

Comment: i asked a question about editing stored procedure because i didn't find any solution in asp.net core : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439547/how-to-avoid-temptable-in-union-all-when-queries-contain-different-order-by-and

Answer (score 0):

`OrderByDescending` could be useful to fix it. Like below:

```
List<Product> SortedList = products.OrderByDescending(o => o.StockQuantity).ToList();
```

Comment: it is useful but not related to my problem :)
products are already sorted in sp, i am looking for a method to not load 10k products every times that page loads.

Comment: thank you so much , i still didn't find any solution so i asked a question about editing sp : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439547/how-to-avoid-temptable-in-union-all-when-queries-contain-different-order-by-and