# How To Avoid TempTable in Union All when queries contain DIFFERENT order by and inner join?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, nopcommerce, sqlperformance

What i am trying to do is always sending Product with 0 quantity to the end of an already sorted temp Table **without losing current sorting** (as i described in the following question [How to send Zero Qty Products to the end of a PagedList<Products>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383555/how-to-send-zero-qty-products-to-the-end-of-a-pagedlistproducts))

I have one **Sorted** temptable which is filled (it is sorted by what user has selected like Alphabetic , by Price or by Newer product,sorting is based identity id) :

```
CREATE TABLE #DisplayOrderTmp 
(
    [Id] int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] int NOT NULL
)

sorted #DisplayOrderTmp :
+------------+---------------+  
|     id     |  ProductId    |  
+------------+---------------+  
|     1      |     66873     |  // Qty is 0
|     2      |     70735     |  // Qty is not 0
|     3      |     17121     |  // Qty is not 0
|     4      |     48512     |  // Qty is not 0
|     5      |     51213     |  // Qty is 0
+------------+---------------+
```

I want pass this data to web-page, but before it i need to send product with zero quantity to the end of this list **without loosing current Sorting by**)

My returned data **should be like this** (sorting doesn't changed just 0 quantity products went to the end of list by their order):

```
CREATE TABLE #DisplayOrderTmp4 
(
    [Id] int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] int NOT NULL
)
+------------+---------------+  
|     id     |  ProductId    |  
+------------+---------------+  
|     1      |     70735     |  
|     2      |     17121     |  
|     3      |     48512     | 
|     4      |     66873     |   
|     5      |     51213     |  
+------------+---------------+
```

**P.S**: Its My product Table which i have to inner join with tmptable to find qty of products.

```
    Product Table is like this :
    +------------+---------------+------------------+  
    |     id     |   stockqty    | DisableBuyButton |
    +------------+---------------+------------------+  
    |   17121    |      1        |         0        | 
    |   48512    |      27       |         0        |     
    |   51213    |      0        |         1        |
    |   66873    |      0        |         1        |
    |   70735    |      11       |         0        |
    +------------+---------------+------------------+
```

What i have tried so far is this : (it works **with delay and has performance issue i almost have 30k products**)

```
INSERT INTO #DisplayOrderTmp2 ([ProductId])
        SELECT p2.ProductId
        FROM  #DisplayOrderTmp p2  with (NOLOCK) // it's already sorted table
        INNER JOIN Product prd with (NOLOCK) 
        ON p2.ProductId=prd.Id  
        and prd.DisableBuyButton=0     // to find product with qty more than 0
        group by p2.ProductId  order by min(p2.Id) // to save current ordering

INSERT INTO #DisplayOrderTmp3 ([ProductId])     
        SELECT p2.ProductId     
        FROM  #DisplayOrderTmp p2  with (NOLOCK) //it's already sorted table    
        INNER JOIN Product prd with (NOLOCK)
        ON p2.ProductId=prd.Id  
        and prd.DisableBuyButton=1    // to find product with qty equal to 0
        group by p2.ProductId  order by min(p2.Id) // to save current ordering


        INSERT INTO #DisplayOrderTmp4 ([ProductId]) // finally Union All this two data
          SELECT p2.ProductId FROM  
          #DisplayOrderTmp2 p2  with (NOLOCK)  // More than 0 qty products with saved ordering

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT p2.ProductId   FROM 
        #DisplayOrderTmp3 p2  with (NOLOCK)  //  0 qty products with saved ordering
```

> Is there any way To Avoid creating TempTable in this query?  send 0
>   quantity products of first temptable to the end of data-list without
>   creating three other tempTable , without loosing current ordering based by **Identity ID**.
>   My query has performance problem.

I have to say again that the temptable has a identity insert ID column and it is sorted based sorting type which user passed to Stored-Procedure.
Thank You All :)

Comment: Note your current method does not guarantee order. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) states, "INSERT queries that use SELECT with ORDER BY to populate rows guarantees how identity values are computed but not the order in which the rows are inserted."

Comment: Consider adding 2 columns to each select statement, a result set sequence number (hard-coded integer) and 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY <your desired order>')`. Then wrap those in a `UNION ALL` CTE and order by those 2 columns in the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: the table is already sorted , so it would loose main ordering by

Comment: @DanGuzman it's working on my 30k products

Comment: An important concept in relational database is a table is an unordered set of rows. Although it might work today, it might break tomorrow depending on the execution plan SQL Server chooses. Ordering is deterministic when you select with an ORDER BY clause, not during inserts.

Comment: it returns from a stored-procedure for page number and page-size which customers select, it will great if take a look at my former question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383555/how-to-send-zero-qty-products-to-the-end-of-a-pagedlistproducts

Comment: See the `OFFSET` and `FETCH` clauses in the [ORDER BY documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you :) , you are exactly right but my ecommerce solution uses this way to pass data to IPagedList

Comment: @DanGuzman please help me ! my question still doesn't have a correct solution, what do you suggest? i added more details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the temp table has an index or primary key with `Id` as the leading column. This will help avoid sort operators in the plan for the ordering:

```
CREATE TABLE #DisplayOrderTmp
(
    [Id] int NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] int NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(Id)
);
```

With that index, you should be able to get the result without additional temp tables with reasonable efficiency using a `UNION ALL` query, assuming ProductID is the Product table primary key:

```
WITH products AS (
    SELECT p2.Id, p2.ProductId, prd.stockqty, 1 AS seq
    FROM #DisplayOrderTmp p2
    JOIN Product prd
          ON p2.ProductId=prd.Id
    WHERE prd.stockqty > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p2.Id, p2.ProductId, prd.stockqty, 2 AS seq
    FROM #DisplayOrderTmp p2
    JOIN Product prd
          ON p2.ProductId=prd.Id
    WHERE prd.stockqty = 0
)
SELECT ProductId
FROM products
ORDER BY seq, Id;
```

You mentioned in comments that you ultimately want a paginated result. This can be done in T-SQL by adding `OFFSET` and `FETCH` to the `ORDER BY` clause as below. However, be aware that pagination over a large result set will become progressively slower the further into the result one queries.

```
WITH products AS (
    SELECT p2.Id, p2.ProductId, prd.stockqty, 1 AS seq
    FROM #DisplayOrderTmp p2
    JOIN Product prd
          ON p2.ProductId=prd.Id
    WHERE prd.stockqty > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p2.Id, p2.ProductId, prd.stockqty, 2 AS seq
    FROM #DisplayOrderTmp p2
    JOIN Product prd
          ON p2.ProductId=prd.Id
    WHERE prd.stockqty = 0
)
SELECT ProductId
FROM products
ORDER BY seq, Id
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ORDER BY` without using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT p2.ProductId
FROM #DisplayOrderTmp p2
JOIN Product prd
  ON p2.ProductId=prd.Id  
ORDER BY prd.DisableBuyButton, p2.id;
```

DisableBuyButton = 0 - qnt > 0
DisableBuyButton = 1 - qnt = 0

Comment: it cause losing main ordering by

Answer (score 1):

Seems it only needs an extra something in the order by.

An `IIF` or `CASE` can be used to give a priority to the sorting.

```
SELECT tmp.ProductId
FROM #DisplayOrderTmp tmp
JOIN Product prd
  ON prd.Id = tmp.ProductId
 AND prd.DisableBuyButton IN (0,1)
ORDER BY IIF(prd.DisableBuyButton=0,1,2), tmp.id;
```

Comment: i had to return the data to web-page with same ordering and inserted on a table like the #temptable. thank you for your help